Using React Loady with Laravel 11 SPA to Upload a File (CSRF Issues)
I have set up Laravel 11 for an SPA which is working perfectly. I know this because I have one React app using it. I set up another app for development purposes to use Uploady for file uploads.
This is where I am hitting a wall with a 419 response. In this development app I am using the following:
function App() { 
// etc ...

<Uploady
        multiple={false} 
        autoUpload={true}
        inputFieldName={'file'} 
        forceJsonResponse={true} 
        withCredentials={true}
        debug={true}
        destination={
            { 
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/uploads', 
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                    'Accept': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                    'Referrer-Policy': 'strict-origin-when-cross-origin',
                    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
                    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                }, 
                params: {
                    hello: 'world',
                }
            }
        }>
        
      <div>
        <UploadButton>Upload Files</UploadButton>
      </div>
    </Uploady>

That's all there is to it. I have debug on, and I see the output. The error I get back is 419 and there's the error message of token mismatch.
The endpoint on Laravel 11 isn't protected by the web.php middleware:
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1', 'namespace'=> 'Api/v1'], function($router) 
{
    
Route::post('/uploads', function(Rquest $request)
    {
        \Log::info($request->all());

        return response()->json([
            'status' => true,
            'message' => 'Received the data',
        ], 200)
        ->withHeaders(['Content-Type'=>'application/json; charset=utf-8']);
    });

    Route::get('/posts/paginate', [PostController::class, 'paginate']);

    Route::post('/register', [AuthenticateController::class, 'register'])->name('register');
    Route::post('/login', [AuthenticateController::class, 'login'])->name('login');
});

The endpoint is: http://localhost:8080/api/v1/uploads clearly. My question is what must I do with  to set up the CSRF token and session?
Any suggestions at this time would be really appreciated.
I am looking for a solution that will let me upload a file presently. Later I want to use this with something else to crop and upload images.
